# ASP.NET MVC 4 on Aruba

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, aruba

i tried to look around but i did't find a solution.
I have a web space on aruba and i want to publish the default mvc 4 internet website (you know...home, about, contacts).
I tried to publish but it dont't work.
I read about putting .aspx (useless cause no aspx pages here) or .chstml (i tried) on the route config, but nothing happend. Always HTTP Error 403.14

Does anyone tried to publish an mcv 4 website on aruba? What changes do i have to do?

I'm using Windows 2008 Hosting with, with ASP.NET 4 and Classic Pipeline

Answer (score 0):

If you referring to Aruba.it hosting solutions, they doesn't support mvc projects..

Look at there [Windows hosting solution](http://hosting.aruba.it/hosting_con_spazio.asp?offerta=1)

It support asp.net not asp.net mvc...

If they were support it they would have wrote it

Answer (score 0):

If ASP.NET works for you, you can bundle the MVC dll's with your project (so that theres a System.web.mvc.dll in your project's bin folder.

And it should just work.

Answer (score 0):

Aruba supports Mvc4. You just have to remember to publish all the dll as told by Mvison (so mvc dll, sql ce dll, and so on) and also give the write permission to that folder, otherwise they won't allow them to run (think it's a safety policy)